# deleting characters in C++ string

Tags: c++

I have strings of the following form in C++

```
   string variable1="This is stackoverflow \"Here we go "1234" \u1234 ABC";
```

Now in this string I want to delete all characters except alphabets(From a to b, and A to B) and numbers. So that my output becomes

```
   variable1="This is stackoverflow Here we go 1234 u1234 ABC";
```

I tried to check for each and every character using pointers but found it very inefficient. Is there an efficient way to achieve the same using C++/C?

Comment: how is it inefficient perhaps some code? Remember that when removing a char from a string in the middle means that all the consecutive ones have to be moved one back, You'll have to use a temporary string to make sure that that doesn't happen.

Comment: This is C++, please remove the C tag.

Comment: Removed 'C' from subject and tags. 'C' does not have a 'string' type and when you say 'C++/C' strings, people assume you mean nul-terminated character arrays.

Answer (score 7):

Use `std::remove_if`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

variable1.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        variable1.begin(),
        variable1.end(),
        [] (char c) { return !std::isalnum(c) && !std::isspace(c); }
    ),
    variable1.end()
);
```

Note that the behaviors of `std::isalnum` and `std::isspace` depend on the current locale.

Comment: That erases single character.

Comment: I dont know why but its giving me  error: no matching function for call to ‘remove_if(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::

Comment: Also I am running on linux gcc compiler

Comment: @0x499602D2 OP asked about letters, digits and—implicitly through his example—spaces.

Comment: You should use `assign(variable1.begin(), std::remove_if(...))` instead of `erase`. `erase` will only remove one character at position returned from `remove_if`.

Comment: @JannatArora did you include the required headers? I updated the example.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec2e772f90c7dcf4 You're calling one argument overload of `erase`.

Comment: @Snps std::string::erase removes from that point until end of the string. I think your thinking of a different erase.

Comment: @JannatArora did you specify `-std=c++11` and do you use a recent implementation of the standard library?

Comment: @Xonar Wrong, one argument overload of erase removes one character. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase

Comment: Actually i can not use c++11 is there any other way out by just using C++

Comment: C++11 *is* C++. It is quite literally the current *definition* of C++.

Comment: Yes I understand but since my company uses the old one therefore I am forced to do so :)

Comment: @Snps Ah I looked at the overload for erase(size_t) my bad

Comment: @JannatArora `std::remove_if` is in C++03. You can write a function and pass a function pointer to it instead of the lambda and it should work

Comment: Can u illustrate my a small example...i am new to it

Comment: @JannatArora http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e67b65659dbf6f9. Also, I’m “you”, not “u”.

Answer (score 2):

working code example:
**http://ideone.com/5jxPR5**

```
bool predicate(char ch)
    {
     return !std::isalnum(ch);
    }

int main() {
    // your code goes here


    std::string str = "This is stackoverflow Here we go1234 1234 ABC";

    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), predicate), str.end());
    cout<<str;
    return 0;
}
```